# Cannot add or update a child row... why did i get this error?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$a='asfda'; $b='sdgdfgd'; $c='sdfdsfg'; $d='sgdfgdsfg';

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `confirmation`, `name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('','$a','$b','$c','$d')");
```

i have 10 more column in my user table that i want to leave empty while one of them is 'cityID' (foreign key), its keep giving me this error...

> "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`php_first`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`city id`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id`))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you've created an index in users table which is references to `id` field in `cities` table. Remove that index and you'll get rid of this error.

I suggested that you remove the index because your index seems to be of no help otherwise when you have foreign key index, you have to make you that an entry for foreign key must exist before you can insert any entry to child record.

Logically think of it like this. You are going to create a child whose father doesn't exist ;)

Comment: tnx a lot! at the end i just added a defult city to the city table so i wont have a "child whose father doesn't exist" and i'll still have the city connect to the user... :)

Comment: Good, but i don't see the point why would you wanna connect city to user.

Comment: Its the city where the user lives and i have some options where I need to search by city, so i have to know who lives where...

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("set foreign_key_checks=0");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `confirmation`, `name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('','$a','$b','$c','$d')");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, you have a not-NULL constraint on `cities` in your table.

This gets reported as a foreign key violation.  You can see an example [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9).

So, this should fix your problem:

```
alter table modify column cities <whatever the type>
```

This will allow `NULL` values.